File Sharing between two ubuntu pc's
Two ubuntu 22.04 PC's sharing  an ethernet connection to router. Want to share all files between both PC's.   Under 'sharing' on settings there is a ref to dav:// implying the use of Webdav and appache server.  But is this the only option - there are others ssh, samba etc all with different protocols, use different ports? Some require detailed set up in config files some apparently not.   So what is the easiest to use with the simplest set up? Security is not an issue and I can configure the firewall of both machines as necessary. Any general advice?

See at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1530773/sharing-any-folder-similar-to-windows-file-sharing/1530780?noredirect=1#comment2692965_1530780
